# Как работает генератор случайных чисел в компьютере?

Tags: java, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Во многих программах используются случайные числа. Многие ЯП предоставляют API для генерации случайных чисел. Но эти числа не могут взяться просто так из ниоткуда. Генерируются ли они процессором на основании каких-то физических законов, и если да, то как? Или каким-то другим способом?
А если нет, то интересно узнать, как они генерируются в java при использовании `Math.random()`?

Comment: если, образно, опустить руку в реку времени в которой кищат милисекунды, то выловленную одну из них условились считать случайной.